# Javascript - make a list with bootstrap media objects

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

What would be the best way to create a list with bootstrap media objects with javascript.

```
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="..." alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I am fetching json data from an api endpoint and was thinking of making something like in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/sTLbj/4/), or using maybe some templating engine. So, I wonder how would I do this here and if it would look messy with creating all the elements necessary for bootstrap media object component?

```
function makeUL(array) {
    // Create the list element:
    var list = document.createElement('ul');

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Create the list item:
        var item = document.createElement('li');

        // Set its contents:
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));

        // Add it to the list:
        list.appendChild(item);
    }

    // Finally, return the constructed list:
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to clarify how you are planning to handle the data inside media object. What i mean is,

- Are you going to get the data from a database or a JSON file or sth?
- Which proggramming language are you using? PHP, ASP, Python... or None
- Do you have to do this with JavaScript, because it can be achieved with any other languages

In order to create an array of `something`, you should define that `something` first.

> Here is a starting point for you:

First create an empty div with an id eg: #yourContainerID
Then create a new js file, and don't forget to give referance to that file.
And put these code inside that JS file

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url: 'yourFile.json',  //Here you will fetch records 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

          var mediaData; // Here you create data to put into container
          mediaData = '';

          for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            mediaData += '<div class="media">';
            mediaData += '<div class="media-left">';
            ...
                mediaData += data.yourData // Your data
            ...
            mediaData += '</div>' // You close divs
          }
          $('#yourContainerID').html(mediaData);
      }
});
});
```

Since I don't have a clue on your data structure, this is just for demo. You have to edit the code for your needs.

Comment: I am fetching json data and creating an array of objects there, the code in the question is just an example, not the real current implementation. Also, the language, would be javascript, I apologise if I wasn't clear enough with that.

Comment: I edited my previous post. Just look at it and let me know if you need sth else.